# CSS layout breaks without border on div

Tags: css

I've came across with this issue several times. Still have no clue what causes this.

Reproduce:

1. Open http://jsbin.com/ibowed/1/edit
2. In CSS panel find `.l-search-index .top {` @ line 26
3. change `border: 1px solid #ff0000;` to `border: 0;`
4. whaaat?

Browser: chrome, but I think u can try in any other..

Please advise!

Comment: May be a problem with jsbin.. or is this happening in your testing code too?

Comment: In clean environment: http://jsbin.com/ibowed/1/quiet -> F12, check off border on `.top` classed div. Same.

Comment: +1; very odd. It's being triggered by the negative  `margin-top` on the inner div; remove that from the equation and toggling the border now works as expected. I can't explain for the moment why the style of the inner element should have this effect on the outer element though.

Comment: That's just how margins work. They naturally overlap. See my shitty non-technical answer and jsbin test answer.

Comment: @Dominic - indeed, and +1 for the answer. I hadn't had a chance to think it through yet to reach that conclusion, but you've obviously hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @Spudley :) I don't think zxitro's test makes it obvious what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quite unintuitive case of collapsing margins:

[§ 8.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) of the CSS Spec explains how margins are handled and under which circumstances they collapse. The rules are not too easy to understand (has several special cases), but I quote the relevant parts of the spec for you:

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (**which might or
> might not be siblings**) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
> that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
> margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> Two margins are adjoining if and only if: no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and **no border separate them**

<sup>(emphasized by me)</sup>

So, as soon as you remove the border, the vertical margins of your elements collapse. Your case makes it a bit complicated since you have negative margins.

To fix this you could set the `overflow` property or apply a `padding:1px` on the `.top` element.

Comment: The key part here is "*which might or might not be siblings*". In the original example, its easy to see that it was non-intuitive that the margins might affect each other.

Comment: Thanks for the referencing to specs!

Answer (score 7):

It's to do with the way margins overlap, and how certain properties force them to be contained. If you place 2x divs on a page, both with margins 100px, the spacing between those divs will be 100px. Not 200px. That's because the margins are allowed to overlap other margins. That's just how margins work. It's a good thing.

But if you put a div inside another div, both with margins, then the those margins also overlap. The child element's margins overlap the parent's.

But, some properties — border, as you've discovered, but also padding and overflow — force the parent to contain the margins of its child instead of overlapping them.

I'm sure someone can give a more technical explanation, but that's how I think about what's happening.

Here is a simplified test case: http://jsbin.com/ukodus/2/
Remove the `//` before any of the lines of CSS to see the effect.

---

*"This behavior is called margin collapse. Only top/bottom margins will collapse, not left/right."* — @cimmanon

Comment: This behavior is called *margin collapse*.  Only top/bottom margins will collapse, not left/right.

Comment: +1, thanks, your test cases are very helpful. I would accept this answer also!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
.l-search-index .top{border: 0; height: 70%; overflow: auto;}
```

You have to add an overflow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helps :), but as I mentioned in my question, I really want to know the background of this phenomena.

Comment: Here is the link that will help your queries. http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html

 - Read them in context to your two classes 1).l-search-index .top and 2).l-search-index .icon - @zsitro